# small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (128,128)) cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.5) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, opencv, resize

i'm using python 3.6 and i get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\mchaf\Music\face\facerec_from_webcam_faster.py", line 49, in 
>       small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (128,128))
>   cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.5) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

What should i do to fix this issue?
Here is my line code

```
from distutils.core import setup
import face_recognition
from cv2 import *
import subprocess
import time

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

known_face_encodings = [
    obama_face_encoding,
    biden_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "Barack Obama",
    "Joe Biden"
]

face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
process_this_frame = True

while True:
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (128,128))

    rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

    if process_this_frame:
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

        face_names = []
        for face_encoding in face_encodings:
            matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
            name = "Unknown"
            time.sleep(5)
            imshow("Operator",frame)
            video_capture.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\mchaf\Desktop\run.bat'])


            if True in matches:
                first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

            face_names.append(name)

    process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the frame processing in this condition

```
if ret:
    cv2.resize...
```

And delete line with

```
Video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It looks your frame is empty thats why you cant resize
The reason is that you release the capture(kind of disconnection) from your webcam. After releasing you want to read new frame but it is empty

Your code is obviously copied from different places. Even if you correct these your code wont work.

For example:

```
...
name = "Unknown"
time.sleep(5) # Why sleep? 
imshow("Operator",frame) # OpenCV cv2 class is missing
video_capture.release() # Why you release the capture? - main error
cv2.destroyAllWindows()   # Why you destroy window if you will want to see result in the next loop
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\mchaf\Desktop\run.bat'])
...
```

Comment: i use this code as face recognition to open application, but it is not finish yet. So i reverse it. If unknown man in frame, the batch file will be run. if man is known, it should be show nothing.

that's why i use script to stop the process, and open new task (batch file)
`imshow("Operator",frame) # OpenCV cv2 class is missing`
`video_capture.release() # Why you release the capture? - main error`
`cv2.destroyAllWindows()   # Why you destroy window if you will want to see result in the next loop`

Comment: do you know what i mean? @Martin. I'm confused to finish this.. maybe you can share an idea, what should i do please.

Comment: Actually I have no idea. Why dont you go to https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition and build first recognition model without opencv and when it is working, add opencv? Like this nobody can have any idea what you are actually doing (like the subprocess thing).

Comment: @MChafidhAlAyyubi check this page: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/18/face-recognition-with-opencv-python-and-deep-learning/ and get inspired.

Comment: To advice you to what you are doing, why dont you create flask app that will receive recognized and unrecognized people and based on that you will create api that will trigger different behavour?   localhost:5000/recognized & localhost:5000/unrecognized. That subprocess thing shouldnt really be there